# I need a help with this script ($.ajax())

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'process.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'loginName=' + $("#loginName").val() + 'loginPass=' + $("#loginPass").val(),
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function(data){
    if(data.success)
    {
        location.href = data.redirect;
    }
    else
    {   
        alert(data.message);
    }
    }
});
```

And here is process.php code:

```
<?
$data = array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if($_POST['loginName'] == "test" && $_POST['loginPass'] == "test")
    {
        $data['redirect'] = "home.php";
        $data['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message'] = "<div id=Message>Your info is wrong...</div>";
        $data['success'] = false;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
?>
```

Sorry, but I'm from the Czech Republic and I don't speak english :D

Comment: what problem are you encountering with this script? =)

Comment: if i post its the same as i write "return false;". I try Chrome developer tools and the page return just this: XHR finished loading: "octopus.zaridi.to/process.php";. but any alert or somthing like this :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data:` misses a `&` right before `loginPass=`, which would lead to a garbled request. But maybe you should give jQuery an data object there anyway (it takes care of proper url encoding):

```
type: 'POST',
data: {loginName: $("#loginName").val(), loginPass: $("#loginPass").val()},
```

A second problem might be the lack of content-type in the php script. Add following on top (just to be sure this isn't why the result goes ignored):

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Another thing: You need more braces in the `if` statement, because `&&` has higher precedence than the `==` comparison:

```
if(($_POST['loginName'] == "test") && ($_POST['loginPass'] == "test")) {
```

Since it is seemingly a PHP error, you must turn on error_reporting(E_ALL) and display_errors in the php.ini; If you still get no content returned from your URL, then add a `print 'test123';` on top. And/or remove the test for REQUEST_METHOD (this adds no security anyway).

Comment: Thanks... i try it, but page still do nothing if i tapping the post button chrome developer tools return this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null   
XHR finished loading: "http://octopus.zaridi.to/process.php".

Comment: @Gabriel: Now this looks clearly like a PHP problem. The URL does return no content. Which PHP version are you using, and are you sure `json_encode()` is available?

Comment: I don't know i'm a begginer with Javascript and ajax and i have never needed json_encode(); in php.

Comment: @Gabriel: It's not available for PHP 5.0 and PHP 5.1 servers (quite old already). That's why you need to check the version.

Comment: @Gabriel: What I also just now noticed, the `type: 'POST'` should be in uppercase. Maybe that's why the request failed, or your REQUEST_METHOD check didn't succeed.

Comment: @Gabriel: Okay well, that explains the problem then. That's an outdated version and does not have the `json_encode()` function, which therefore leads to a fatal error in your PHP script. You can use http://upgradephp.berlios.de/ however as stop-gap measure.

Comment: "maybe you should give jQuery an array" -- that should say "object", not "array".

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, fixed. (It's too awfully similar, since in PHP arrays are hashes anyway.)